# ArangoDB: What is the best way to load a scheme into a new database?

Tags: arangodb

When starting a new instance of ArangoDB, what is the best way to load in a database scheme?

I would like to define collections and indexes in a file, and then feed it to Arango somehow.

Comment: Like creating databases, collections, indexes etc. programmatically? You can write scripts in JavaScript and run them with arangosh against a server: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Administration/Arangosh/

Comment: @CoDEmanX, thanks for your response. Do you have any example on how to do that?

Comment: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/GettingStarted/Arangosh.html#using-arangosh-via-unix-shebang-mechanisms

Answer (score 5):

You can use the option `--javascript.execute` to run a javascript file in the arango shell.
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangodb-shell/options/#--javascriptexecute

There is also a schema evolution tool that is based on XML:
<s>https://github.com/deusdat/migrantverde</s> (deprecated)
Replaced by:
https://github.com/deusdat/arangomigo